# Bitshift time complexity

Tags: java, c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I want to know what is the time-complexity of right bitshift operator >>, preferably in java and if possible other languages like C, Python ... etc too.  Is it O(n) or O(1), where 'n' is the number of bits shifted. I am not looking for a general answer as I know implementation details will differ from each. I want to know which are constant take time O(1), and which take O(n) time.

Comment: The time complexity depends on the capabilities of the underlying hardware. If the alu implements barrel shifters, the operation is performed in a single cycle. Otherwise, n cycles can be necessary for n bits shifted.

Comment: @Ctx nice, thats enlightening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java the primitive integer types are of fixed width i.e. 64, 32,  16 bits. Shifts over the number of bits are modulo the number of bits. Therefore, for practical purposes, you can assume a bit shift is constant time, even if for `1L << 63` you have to do 63 separate shifts.

The same will apply to any language/CPU combination where the language types are mappable to machine types.

Java also has a BigInteger type and other languages also have arbitrarily sized integer types where the number can have a practically arbitrary number of bits. My guess is that a shift in such a case is O(n) where n is the number of bits in the BigInteger.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it would be nice if you could enlighten me about C as well, if possible

Comment: @ytoamn C is pretty much the same as Java except for the lack of a standard arbitrary sized integer and some C compilers support built in integer types up to 128 bits..